# Calling moveTaskToBack twice

Tags: android

I'm creating a Home Screen app. I want that this app work as a lockscreen.
So, when I write down the correct password I use moveTaskToBack to put the task on background what is working perfectly.

Receiving  the Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON I start the same instance of activity using

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(i);
```

What is working too.
But after that, if I put the correct password again and I call moveTaskToBack, it doesn't work.

Resuming: the first time that I call moveTaskToBack it works well but in the second call, it doesn't.

In my manifesto:

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

Comment: are you performing this on main activity??

Comment: @Shiv yes, I have only this one activity in this moment.

Comment: after move task to back finish the activity,

Comment: @Atrix1987 I have only one activity, so If I do that, the app crashes.
I'm adding another activity, maybe with 2 activities it will work (closing the second one).

Comment: Resolved: with two activities it becomes easier. The main activity calls the Locker acitivity, that finishes when the password is written down correctly. When the Locker activity finish, the Main activity calls moveTaskToBack and monitor the ACTION_SCREEN_ON and ACTION_SCREEN_OFF to start the Main actitivity again.